# Internationalise menu items in the menu.xml file using kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, menu, internationalization

I have a menu_main.xml file which contain the menu.
How can I internationalise the items. GetStrint(R.string.blablah) don't accepted by the compiler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_open_website"
        android:title="Open Website"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_quiz"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_show_toast"
        android:title=getString(R.string.name)
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_web"/>
</menu>
```

The error message :

> ParseError at [row,col]:[9,23]
> Message: Des guillemets ouvrants sont attendus pour l'attribut "android:title" associxE9 xE0 un type d'xE9lxE9ment "item".

Thanks a lot for any help.
[Line # 9 is not accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBdt7.png)

Answer (score 0):

at line 9 you have used this code:

```
android:title=getString(R.string.name)
```

which gives you error you can achieve that using this code

```
android:title="@string/name"
```